# Mod rewrite prevening to acces a link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i made a mode_rewrite rule for `http://artplant.websoftit.ro/shop.php?id_cat=1&id=7&subcat=solutii` like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /shop.php?id_cat=$1&id=$2&subcat=$3 [L]
```

and it seems for some reason id doesn't let me to access this link anymore and i don't know why. Can someone tell me what i did wrong my my mode_rewrite rule? This is the link i can't acces anymore `http://artplant.websoftit.ro/engine/app/cos.php?id=1`

Comment: I mean you are rewriting the php files 2 levels deep. What is the `URL` you want to display in the browser for this link `http://artplant.websoftit.ro/shop.php?id_cat=1&id=7&subcat=solutii`

Comment: this one http://artplant.websoftit.ro/1/7/solutii.php

Comment: That's because it's the same as `http://artplant.websoftit.ro/engine/app/cos.php` rewriterule ignores the query string part.  you should prepend the rewriterule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean by prepend, is use a name so that it will match the rule specifically. Like the word **shop.**

Something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ /shop.php?id_cat=$1&id=$2&subcat=$3 [L]
```

Then you can use a URL like this and it won't interfere with your other URL's.

```
http://artplant.websoftit.ro/shop/1/7/solutii.php
```

Comment: hehe thnx mate your code is good but without `^shop/` in front. Can you please explain me the RewriteCond so i can know next time what you did?

Comment: Did this work for you at all? Basically the conditions say if not a `real file` and not a `real directory` process the rewrite rule anyway instead of looking for a real directory and possibly getting 404 error.